# Rails cache store: how to configure redis_cache_store with password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

In my environment file, I have:

```rb
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL_CACHING', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')}
```

In rails console, if I print `REDIS_URL_CACHING`, I get:

```rb
> ENV['REDIS_URL_CACHING']
=> "redis://:mypassword@localhost:6379/0
```

However, if I want to check if rails is connected to redis, I get:

```rb
> Rails.cache.redis.keys
=> false
irb(main):004:0> Rails.cache.redis.keys
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL))
```

My redis.conf file is like:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
requirepass mypassword
```

What am I missing here?

If I remove password option, it's working, but my macBook [gets attacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931292/what-is-redis-change-its-own-configurations).

## EDIT

In [redis gem guide](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb), you can set password for redis like the following:

```rb
redis = Redis.new(url: "redis://:p4ssw0rd@10.0.1.1:6380/15")
# Or 
redis = Redis.new(password: "mysecret")

# And then
redis.set("foo", "bar")
redis.get("foo")
```

However, I'd like to use low-level caching in the way mentioned in the [official low level caching guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def competing_price
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key_with_version}/competing_price", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      Competitor::API.find_price(id)
    end
  end
end
```

Can't figure out how I can config redis gem to use with `Rails.cache.fetch`

Comment: My guess is that way of inputting the password isn't supported. Check out the examples in the PR when this feature was introduced in rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31134#issue-152131596 . It does show inputting password in the URL as you have, but only with the `hiredis` driver. Try that perhaps? Or, if you have the `redis` gem, try initializing the redis client yourself according to the README in https://github.com/redis/redis-rb

Comment: @Kache I've read that guide. I'd like to use low level caching like this one: `Rails.cache.fetch` as recommended by [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching). I cannot figure out how I can achieve this by reading the guide.

Comment: Since the `redis-rb` gem supports the `.new(password: 'pass')` syntax, try passing it in the same way to Rails, like this: `config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: 'http", password: 'pass' }`. I'm guessing Rails passes it on in the same format.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that and let you know.

Comment: @Kache Close call. I set `config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { redis: {url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', password: 'mypassword' }}` And it worked. Thanks for helping. You can post this as answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the testing that's been done, it looks like the only issue is configuring Rail's cache adapter to properly deliver the password to the Redis client during configuration.

In Rails source, [setting the config](https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/a33dbb17b0818e8a2c75581275374bc0853958ca/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/caching.rb#L18) will [pass the latter parameters to the underlying Redis client](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fce2d6a78bbe1d3b58edd888f2cdbcb2890e6d11/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb#L116).

So if this works:

```rb
Redis.new(url: your_url, password: your_pass)
```

Have Rails pass through those settings like so:

```rb
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: your_url, password: your_pass }
```

Comment: `config.cache_store` is located in `config/environments/development.rb`. That's where I set redis configuration. Where should I put that line? I didn't create an initializer for redis.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, you're not initializing `Redis` yourself. My answer is not relevant, I'll delete it.

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange. The rails source for `RedisCacheStore` reads like any of: `{ url: url, password: pass }`, `{ redis: Redis.new(url: url, password: pass) }`, and `{ redis: ->() { Redis.new(url: url, password: pass) } }` should work. Well happy it worked for you. If you really want to figure out what's going in there, you could debug into Rails code and see what's going on with `pry`/`byebug`.

Comment: You're right. I was about to let you know, it's not working. I passed url and password directly without redis key but it's showing ADDRNOTAVAIL again :(

Comment: try one of the other variants I suggested, e.g. `redis: Redis.new(url: url, pass: pw)`, esp since instantiating yourself works, right?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I dockerized redis container, so it cannot be connected with localhost.

Passing url with my docker host machine address and password (like in @Kache's answer) solved problem.